# How to catch event in native javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I have to check does the element visible on the screen (does the user scrolled to element?). I have function which is answer "yes" or "no", but how can I permanently check it? How can i permanently execute this function? How can I catch visibility of the element?

Only native javascript.

Thanks